# Маршрутизация запросов к файлам ASP NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

Расскажите, как вы делаете маршруты для получения файлов

Я нашёл способ, как это сделать, но мне кажется, что есть более лучший

### Я сделал контроллер, который возвращает изображение в ответ на запрос

```
    [HttpGet("getImage/{folder}/{file}")]
    public IActionResult GetImage(string folder, string file)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "images", folder, file);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, GetContentType(extension));
    }

    public string GetContentType(string extension)
    {
        switch (Path.GetExtension(extension))
        {
            case ".bmp": return "Image/bmp";
            case ".gif": return "Image/gif";
            case ".jpg": return "Image/jpeg";
            case ".png": return "Image/png";
            default: break;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

### Затем я зарегистрировал маршрут, который ведёт к контроллеру

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{   
    app.UseRouting();    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {   
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "GetImage",
        pattern: "media/getImage/{folder}/{file}"
        );
    });
}
```

### Теперь я покажу, как сохраняю файлы в каталоге

Сначала я объявляю, название папки, в которой будет сохранён файл

```
string folder = "products"; // Объявляю, папку в которую надо сохранить файл
string folderPath = Path.Combine("images", folder, productDto.Image.FileName); // Создаю путь /images/products/image.png
string filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, folderPath); // Создаю абсолютный путь к файлу, который ведёт к /wwwroot/images/products/image.png

productDto.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew)); // Сохраняю файл
```

### Недостаток моего решения

Если название каталога будет изменено с `/images/products` на `/photos/people/`, то мне придётся перечитывать весь код и искать места, где встречается `/images` и `/products`, чтобы изменить их. 
Мне хочется, чтобы у меня была всего одна точка доступа, которая будет хранить в себе название каталогов. Таким образом, если я изменю название каталогов в этой точке, то название каталогов будет изменено везде, и мне не придётся перечитывать код, чтобы изменить `/images/products` на `/photos/people/`

## Я придумал решение, но может есть более лучший способ?

Моё решение

```
public static string GetImagesFolderName()
{
    return "images";
}

public static string GetProductsFolderName()
{
    return "products";
}
```

Теперь если мне придётся создать путь к папке `/images/products`, то я сделаю так 
`string path = Path.Combine(GetImagesFolderName(), GetProductsFolderName());`

Если название каталога `images` изменится на `photos`, то я просто изменю метод `GetImagesFolderName`, и теперь везде в коде будут генерироваться пути `/photos/products/`.

```
public static string GetImagesFolderName()
{
    return "photos";
}
```